# Issue with overlapping labels in phylogenetic trees in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly, ggtree

I use R shiny and I want to build an interactive phylogenetic tree, but `geom_label_repel` function or `guide_axis` doesn’t seem to work. Any solutions on this? I use **ggplotly** and this is a newick file that I didn’t create myself. Here is some of my code. Note: scale_x_discrete doesn't improve anything

```
library(ggtree)
library(plotly)

tree -> read.tree("file.newick")

p1 <- ggtree(tree, color ="black")

p2 <- p1 + geom_text(size = 3, aes(label = label)) + scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE, n.dodge = 2))

p3 <- plotly::ggplotly((p2)) %>% layout(height = 2000, width =1800)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `geom_text_repel()`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake it is geom_label_repel(), which doesn't seem to work in ggplotly but only for ggplot. In my case I want to build an interactive phylogenetic tree in R shiny.

Comment: Ah. I would make that clearer in your question - you might (?) have a hard time getting labels to repel in ggplotly